# setState() adds a Proxy object to property instead of string value in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

This is a very weird problem and I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple.

When I load a new component `AddNewCategory`, I initially set a  an empty string to a `text` property on `this.state`. Logging on console shows the `text` value as empty too.

I update this value using `onChange` of `Button` component. I know that the `text` property is so far updating as expected because the value of the input field changes accordingly.

```
<Button onChange={text=>this.setState({})}>
```

But when I try to retrieve the value of `text` property, I see that instead of a string, the `text` is now assigned a `Proxy` object.
[image]

I'm only trying to get the value of the input field so I can pass the value on to an action creator.

Here's the entire code,

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';

class AddNewCategory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      text: ''
    };
    console.log('after initialising constructor');
    console.log(this.state);
    this.onContinueButtonPress = this.onContinueButtonPress.bind(this);
  }
  onContinueButtonPress() {
    console.log('after onContinueButtonPress');
    console.log(this.state);
    this.props.addNewCategory('Random Value');
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Name your new task list</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Things to do today.."
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={(text)=>this.setState({text: text})}
        />
        <Button
          title={'Continue'}
          onPress={this.onContinueButtonPress}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default AddNewCategory;
```

Comment: I thought of using redux-form to get around this, but to add redux-form at this point only to resolve this seems like an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I am sorry, but why are you giving an onChange prop to a Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you are giving an onChange prop to a Button component.

Anyway, for a TextInput, you should give the onChangeText property.

```
<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
```

Other properties have been omitted.

Using just `onChange` is like handling the usual onChange event when doing web development, where the first parameter to the callback method only gives the event; to get the actual input value you have to say `event.target.value`.

```
onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target.value)}
```